# A linux distro that supports Ralink's 3090 (RT3090) wireless driver out of the box

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I was wondering if such distro exists, I tried the majority of them (Ubuntu 10.10 or older, fedora 16 and older, Archlinux, Mint)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 distros is a [little bit less than a majority](http://www.distrowatch.com).

In any case, according to [this page](http://www.tech-juice.org/2011/10/02/fixing-ralink-3090-wireless-problems-on-linux/), Ubuntu 12.04 (and, therefore, probably Mint 13) supports it out of the box.

You should also be aware that while things sometimes don't work out of the box on linux, a little googling can usually give you [the answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1669283).

Comment: Thanks a lot. By majority I meant the most popular and therefore it would be difficult for other distros to support this "device" if the above-mentioned didn't (anyhow my bad for such assumption) I agree on the googling part but this "device" in particular has caused a lot of headache for me and thought if I could find a distro that supports it by default would be great.